# Using c code defines in c++ (Static Code Warnings)

Tags: c++, c, static-code-analysis

maybe this was asked before, but could not find this specific problem.

My case is regarding using C defines in C++ code. Usually, this should be straight forward, but in my case there a bit problem with the static code analyzer..

Here is the case:

**some.h**

```
typedef double DOUBLE; // This usually defined in different file
#define RAD_TO_DEG ((DOUBLE)57.29577951)
```

**some.cpp**

```
sppMalParams.setMaxOperatingRangeRel2Nominal4AzimuthAngle_lower(
  vfc::CRadian32(-1.0F * ABSOLUT_LIMIT_AZI * static_cast<vfc::float32_t>(RAD_TO_DEG )));
```

The problem here is that, the static code analyzer sees DEG_TO_RAD defined back in the .h file, and throws a warning about old style casting, even though I cast it again in C++ with the new style casting.
The other problem is that I cannot edit the .h file (simple solution will be remove the casting there and problem solved).
Can some one point to some kind of alternative, how to deal with this problem.

Comment: Why do you need the `(DOUBLE)` cast at all?  The floating point constant is already a double.

Comment: What is `DEG_TO_RAD`? You defined only `RAD_TO_DEG`.

Comment: As you cannot fix the issue by changing header, you might use `#pragma` or similar to disable locally the warnings. (better then to wrap offending code).

Comment: What is the static analyser? It must have some attributes for disabling the warning in this line.

Comment: You could use an `extern "C"` block to redefine the macro, assuming the header is in C